# LDAP Client Library

Tags: c#, java, c++, ldap, ldap-client

I'm trying to write my own LDAP Client Library.
Would you like to give me some examples of such libraries which use OOP.
They can be written in C++, Java, C#, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would your solution be better than one of the many free, mature, tested client libraries available?

Comment: What have you already tried to do ?

Comment: If you don't already know how to do it, I would stop now. You will need to implement all sorts of things you haven't dreamed of, such as ASN.1 for a start, which is a major task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, LDAP can be connected through javax.naming.ldap.* packages which comes in standard distribution. I found the following two links, where in you can get sample codes.

http://www.adamretter.org.uk/blog/entries/LDAPTest.java

http://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/LdapBasicExample.java?r=2